# Reading itunes XML file with PHP DOM method

Tags: php, xml, parsing, xml-parsing, itunes

I'm having some trouble in getting information from my itunes XML feed which you can peek at here: http://c3carlingford.org.au/podcast/C3CiTunesFeed.xml

I need to get the information from each of the inner `<item>` tags. An example of one of these is as follows:

```
<item>
    <title>What to do when a viper bites you</title>
    <itunes:subtitle/>
    <itunes:summary/>
    <!-- 4000 Characters Max ******** -->
    <itunes:author>Ps. Phil Buechler</itunes:author>
    <itunes:image href="http://www.c3carlingford.org.au/podcast/itunes_cover_art.jpg"/>
    <enclosure url="http://www.ccccarlingford.org.au/podcast/C3C-20120722PM.mp3" length="14158931" type="audio/mpeg"/>
    <guid isPermaLink="false">61bc701c-b374-40ea-bc36-6c1cdaae8042</guid>
    <pubDate>Sun, 22 Jul 2012 19:30:00 +1100</pubDate>
    <itunes:duration>40:01</itunes:duration>
    <itunes:keywords>
        Worship, Reach, Build, Holy Spirit, Worship, C3 Carlingford
    </itunes:keywords>
</item>
```

---

**Now i have had some success!**
I have been able to get the title out of it all:

```
<?php 
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    $dom->load('http://c3carlingford.org.au/podcast/C3CiTunesFeed.xml');
    $items = $dom->getElementsByTagName('item');

    foreach($items as $item){                       
        $title = $item->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue;
            echo $title . '<br />';
    };

?>
```

But I can't seem to get anything else out... I'm new to all this!

---

So What I need to get out includes:

1. The `<itunes:author>` value.
2. The url attribute value from the `<enclosure>` tag

---

Would someone help me getting these two values out?

Comment: Why DOMDocument and not SimpleXML? http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`DOMXPath`](http://php.net/domxpath) to do this and make your life a lot easier:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$doc->loadXML( $xml); // $xml = file_get_contents( "http://www.c3carlingford.org.au/podcast/C3CiTunesFeed.xml")

// Initialize XPath    
$xpath = new DOMXpath( $doc);
// Register the itunes namespace
$xpath->registerNamespace( 'itunes', 'http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd');

$items = $doc->getElementsByTagName('item');    
foreach( $items as $item) {
    $title = $xpath->query( 'title', $item)->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $author = $xpath->query( 'itunes:author', $item)->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $enclosure = $xpath->query( 'enclosure', $item)->item(0);
    $url = $enclosure->attributes->getNamedItem('url')->value;

    echo "$title - $author - $url\n";
}
```

You can see from [the demo](http://viper-7.com/KssKSB) that this will output:

```
What to do when a viper bites you - Ps. Phil Buechler - http://www.ccccarlingford.org.au/podcast/C3C-20120722PM.mp3
```

Comment: @BenPotter - "having trouble" isn't an error message. What's going wrong?

Comment: haha sorry - it's the morning over here. I am right to copy and paste your code on my site - but I need to setup the $xml variable. How do I do this when it is located at: http://c3carlingford.org.au/podcast/C3CiTunesFeed.xml?

I tried like this but it didn't work: $xml = simplexml_load_file("http://c3carlingford.org.au/podcast/C3CiTunesFeed.xml");

Comment: Set `$xml = file_get_contents( "http://www.c3carlingford.org.au/podcast/C3CiTunesFeed.xml");`

Comment: great that worked awesomly - do you mind editing your answer for the sake of other lookers?

Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, You can do it with simplexml.

Here is the sample code:

```
<?php

 $x = simplexml_load_file("http://c3carlingford.org.au/podcast/C3CiTunesFeed.xml");

  foreach ($x->channel->item as $item) { 
    $otherNode = $item->children('http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd');  
    echo $item->title .'---'.$otherNode->author;  
    echo "\n";
 } 
?>
```

**OutPut:**

What to do when a viper bites you---Ps. Phil Buechler

Living Water, Let the River Flow!---Ps. Phil Buechler

The Call of God to Forgive One Another AM & PM---Ps. Richard Botta

The Call of God to Evangelise AM & PM---Rob Waugh

The Call of God to Love One Another AM & PM---Rob Waugh

Hope this help!

Comment: this is good - but I need the url attribute from the enclosure tab too.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [simpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php) children

$item->children('itunes', TRUE);

So you have an array with all the tag itunes:duration, itunes:subtitle ....

```
<?php

 $x = simplexml_load_file("http://c3carlingford.org.au/podcast/C3CiTunesFeed.xml");

  foreach ($x->channel->item as $item) { 
    $otherNode = $item->children('itunes', TRUE); 
    echo $otherNode->duration;
    echo "\n";
    echo $otherNode->author; 
    echo "\n";
    echo $otherNode->subtitle; 
    echo "\n";
  } 
?>
```